# How can I count the number of records that have a unique value in a particular field in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a record set that includes a date field, and want to determine how many unique dates are represented in the record set.

Something like:

```
Record.find(:all).date.unique.count
```

but of course, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

What you're going for is the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) FROM records
```

ActiveRecord has this built in:

```
Record.count('date', :distinct => true)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using multiple columns as a scope?

Comment: This is now deprecated (rails 4), see answer below.

Answer (score 122):

This has changed slightly in rails 4 and above `:distinct => true` is now deprecated. Use:

```
Record.distinct.count('date')
```

Or if you want the date and the number:

```
Record.group(:date).distinct.count(:date)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Use `.count('DISTINCT date')`

Comment: I ended up using `Record.group(:date).count.count`.

Comment: If you group the elements there is no need for distinct.
Use `Record.group(:date).count(:date)` to get the date and the numbers of occurences.

Answer (score 18):

the latest `#count` on rails source code only accept 1 parameter.
see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count

so I achieved the requirement by

```
Record.count('DISTINCT date')
```

Answer (score 16):

Outside of SQL:

```
Record.find(:all).group_by(&:date).count
```

ActiveSupport's [Enumerable#group_by](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/Enumerable.html#M001795) is indispensable.

Comment: I recognize that the author of this answer specifically notes that this solution is for counting outside of SQL, but it cannot be understated: **don't do this**. This fetchs ALL records (no upper bound) and full attributes, loads ALL into memory as model instances, enumerates over ALL to shove into an unbounded number of array values in a Hash (particularly problematic with something with as many cardinalities as a timestamp column is likely to have), simply to get a count of the number of keys. Let the database do the work for you and use the built-in AR methods noted in other answers.

Answer (score 10):

Detailing the answer:

```
Post.create(:user_id => 1, :created_on => '2010-09-29')
Post.create(:user_id => 1, :created_on => '2010-09-29')
Post.create(:user_id => 2, :created_on => '2010-09-29')
Post.create(:user_id => null, :created_on => '2010-09-29')

Post.group(:created_on).count
# => {'2010-09-29' => 4}

Post.group(:created_on).count(:user_id)
# => {'2010-09-29' => 3}

Post.group(:created_on).count(:user_id, :distinct => true) # Rails <= 3
Post.group(:created_on).distinct.count(:user_id) # Rails = 4
# => {'2010-09-29' => 2}
```

Answer (score 9):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33089246/1103543), in Rails 4, using `(...).uniq.count(:user_id)` as mentioned in other answers (for this question and elsewhere on SO) will actually lead to an extra `DISTINCT` being in the query:

`SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ...`

What we actually have to do is use a SQL string ourselves:

`(...).count("DISTINCT user_id")`

Which gives us:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ...`

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure you have an index on the field in your db, or else that query will quickly become sloooow.

(It's much better to do this in SQL, otherwise you pull the entire db table into memory just to answer the count.)

Comment: nex3's answer will correctly generate the `COUNT` SQL statement. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations

Comment: Good tip about the index, though.