# rails COUNT SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, count, distinct

I'm recording the number of times users watch a series of videos.  Now I'm trying to make a graph of the number of users who watch any video each day.

```
UserVideoWatching.where("created_at >= ? AND user_id != ?",1.month.ago, User.elephant.id).group("DATE(created_at)").reorder('created_at').count
```

produces the sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE(created_at) AS date_created_at FROM `user_video_watchings` WHERE (created_at >= '2013-01-27 10:43:24' AND user_id != 7) GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY created_at
```

which produces the correct results for all videos watched each day, but as I said I want to only show each user once.

The sql I want is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count_all, DATE(created_at) AS date_created FROM `user_video_watchings` WHERE (created_at >= '2013-01-27 10:33:18' AND user_id != 7) GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY created_at
```

so i thought

```
UserVideoWatching.where("created_at >= ? AND user_id != ?",1.month.ago, User.elephant.id).group("DATE(created_at)").reorder('created_at').select('COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count_all, DATE(created_at) AS date_created')
```

would do what I wanted. But this gives

```
[#<UserVideoWatching >, #<UserVideoWatching >]
```

rather than a hash.

Any ideas?

I'm using rails 3.1 and mysql

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `distinct.count(:attribute_name)`.

(In Rails 3 use: `count(:user_id, distinct: true)` instead)

Thus:

```
UserVideoWatching.
  where("created_at >= ? AND user_id != ?", 1.month.ago, User.elephant.id).
  group("DATE(created_at)").
  reorder('created_at').
  distinct.
  count(:user_id)
```

Not able to test but I think that'll produce the SQL you're after.

Comment: deprecated in rails 4 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19362288/670433 for the solution which is to use ModelName.distinct.count(:attribute_name)

Comment: How do you return all of the attributes of the model?

Answer (score 20):

In Rails 4, using `(...).uniq.count(:user_id)` as mentioned in other answers (for this question and elsewhere on SO) will actually lead to an extra `DISTINCT` being in the query:

`SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ...`

What we actually have to do is use a SQL string ourselves:

`(...).count("DISTINCT user_id")`

Which gives us:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

Should use distinct, in rails 5.0.1, distinct equal uniq, but

```
[11] pry(main)> Needremember.distinct.count(:word)
(1.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "needremembers"."word") FROM "needremembers"
[12] pry(main)> Needremember.uniq.count(:word)
DEPRECATION WARNING: uniq is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1 (use distinct instead) (called from __pry__ at (pry):12)
   (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "needremembers"."word") FROM "needremembers"
```