# Error counting the number of records with a unique value in a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a field called `deviceID` and I am trying to get the number of unique values of that field in my database (MongoDB).  I was looking at examples in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-records-that-have-a-unique-value-in-a-particular-f), yet none of them were working for me.  I am using Rails 4.2.2 and I also have these lines of code currently working:

Example 1:

```
<p id="total">Total number of database entries: <%= DistributedHealth.count %></p>
```

Example 2:

```
<% @distributed_healths.each do |distributed_health| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= distributed_health.deviceID %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

These are some of my failed attempts at getting this done.

Failed attempt #1:

```
<%= DistributedHealth.distinct.count(:deviceID) %>
```

Error for #1:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Failed attempt #2:

```
<%= DistributedHealth.distinct.count('deviceID') %>
```

Error for #2:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Failed attempt #3 (I know this is for Rails 3 but I was desperate):

```
<%= DistributedHealth.count('deviceID', :distinct => true) %>
```

Error for #3:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

I can post any additional code that would be helpful, any help is greatly appreciated.  I will update this post if I get this working.  Thank you in advance.

Clayton

EDIT 1:

From my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem "moped"
gem 'bson_ext'
```

SOLUTION:

As was posted below the code I needed was

```
DistributedHealth.distinct('deviceID').count
```

Comment: Which library/gem are you using to access mongo db?

Comment: @GavinMiller refer to EDIT 1 please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
DistributedHealth.distinct('deviceID').count
```

You want to grab the distinct `deviceID`s using [`distinct`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Adistinct) and then count them using [`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-count) (or [`Array#length`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-length) if you want to remind yourself that you're really counting the elements in an array rather than directly querying the database for the count).

Comment: Worked like a charm, I very much appreciate this.  Thank you.