# Count distinct pairs of attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class `Restaurant`: 
`Restaurant(id: integer, name: string, url: string, address: string`

I would like to get all the different combinations of `url` and `name` and count them. How can I do that?

I've tried

`Restaurant.select(:url, :name).distinct.count`

but I get:

`No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: It works with my models. just for curiosity, try `Restaurant.all.select(:url, :name).distinct`.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add the `.count` that is what is causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
Restaurant.pluck(:url, :name).uniq.count
```

More here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

And also check this question [Rails: select unique values from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column)

Comment: For more on counting uniq field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-records-that-have-a-unique-value-in-a-particular-f

Comment: Wrong answer, the above will FIRST query all records into memory, THEN count the unique combination inside Ruby, not the db. The right way to do this would be: `Restaurant.count("DISTINCT(url, name)")`