# Is that good solution?

Tags: ruby

I've got table with different actions from users, it looks like that

```
| User_ID       | Action        | 
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| 10            | View          | 
| 8             | Connect       | 
| 10            | View          |   
| 12            | View          |   
| 10            | View          |
```

And i want to count how many users made "View" action.
So i made Query

`Actions.where( action: "View" ).group(:User_ID).count`

But it showed me

`{10=>3, 12=>1}`

So I added second ".count" at the end

`Actions.where( action: "View" ).group(:User_ID).count.count`

And now it's working properly

Is double count here only and proper way?

Comment: What output do you want? Double counting is counting how many counts you have, which discards the counting in formation, so that seems like a waste of effort.

Comment: @tadman I want only number that shows double counting way

Comment: Can you explain what that means by way of a concrete example here? Do you want, literally, just `2`?

Comment: @tadman Yes, its for admin panel to count specific action per session but not count duplicates

Comment: Consider doing a [distinct count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-records-that-have-a-unique-value-in-a-particular-f) instead of this double-count.

Comment: @tadman sure! thank you!

Comment: Seems like this is solved, so either you (OP) or @tadman should write an answer